# jelastic Tomcat 8 access to storage

Tags: jelastic

I am evaluating jelastic for use with Tomcat 8 and Postgres 9.5.

Does a user have ssh access to the instance that is running these services?
Does Tomcat have access to the local storage, or can you attach storage that Tomcat can create and read files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a user have ssh access to the instance that is running these services?

Yes, a user have ssh access to the any instance. The authentication procedure in Jelastic SSH Gateway is divided into two independent parts:

- connection from end user to Gateway (external authentication)
- connection from Gateway to users’ container (internal authentication)

Both parts of the authentication procedure are based on a standard SSH protocol, using public/private keypairs.

[image: A standard SSH protocol]

With Jelastic SSH Gateway, you can easily access:

- **the whole account** where you can navigate across your environments and containers using an interactive menu without extra authentication

[image: Access to the whole account]

- **separate containers directly** while working with them remotely via additional tools (e.g. [Capistrano](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-capistrano)) or using SFTP and FISH protocols.

[image]

While accessing containers via SSH, a user receives all required permissions and additionally can manage the main services with **sudo** commands of the following kind (and others):

- **sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start**
- **sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop**
- **sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat restart**
- **sudo /etc/init.d/memcached status**
- **sudo /etc/init.d/mongod reload**
- **sudo /etc/init.d/nginx upgrade**
- **sudo /etc/init.d/httpd help**

Using our documentation you’ll find out how to:

- [generate SSH key](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-generate-key)
- [add SSH key](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-add-key)
- [access environments and containers](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access)

> Does Tomcat have access to the local storage, or can you attach storage that Tomcat can create and read files?

Jelastic supported the [local storage](https://docs.jelastic.com/mount-external-server) and the dedicated storage container.

Jelastic **Dedicated Storage Container** is a special type of node, based on Docker centos7 image. Being developed specially for data storing, it provides a number of the appropriate benefits:

- being delivered with the corresponding software (i.e. NFS & RPC) already pre-installed, so such a container can be used as a storage immediately after the creation without any additional configurations required
- compared to other common-purposed Jelastic nodes, Dedicated Storage Container provides the enlarged amount of disk space, which allows to persist a comparatively bigger data volumes (herewith, the particular value depends on your service provider’s settings and can vary according to your account type).

Some tips on this container type usage and examples it can be leveraged in the best way are revealed within the corresponding [use case](https://docs.jelastic.com/dedicated-storage) description.

And below we'll consider how to set up such Storage server inside your Cloud and some tips on its management:

- [Storage container creation](https://docs.jelastic.com/dedicated-storage-container#creation)
- [Storage container management](https://docs.jelastic.com/dedicated-storage-container#management)

If you don't have root permissions, please contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Applications you run on tomcat have access to storage on the running system is based on several things. There are layers of security. Tomcat literally has access to whatever user you run it under has access to. That's true in both Windows and Linux environments. A running service has operable services defined as soon as you decide to log in.